# Django access object attribute in choice form

Tags: python, django, choicefield

I have a choice form, which allows user to choose employees with specific range assigned to them.

```
class ReservationBookingForm(forms.Form):
    employee = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset = Employee.objects.none(),
        #widget = forms.RadioSelect,
        empty_label = None, 
        required = True,
        label = '',
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'input-lg text-center'}),
        )
    def __init__(self, rangeId, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReservationBookingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['employee'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(Q(range = rangeId ) | Q(range = 'B'))
```

What i want to do is display choice option as Employee.first_name and Employee.last_name. I really don't want to do that through unicode method.

Is there a way to do that?

What i get(without unicode) is:

```
option1 - Employee Object
option2 - Employee Object
```

What i want:

```
option1 - John Doe
option2 - Jack Doe
```

but i want to achieve this without overriding unicode method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end of [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) section:

> The `__str__` (`__unicode__` on Python 2) method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices; to provide customized representations, subclass `ModelChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance`. This method will receive a model object, and should return a string suitable for representing it.

In your case:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "{} {}".format(obj.first_name, obj.last_name)

class ReservationBookingForm(forms.Form):
    employee = MyModelChoiceField(...)
    ...
```